# sql error in syntax for age search using between, date_add and getdate

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing an age filter in my search results, but I am getting an error in my syntax:

Here's my php for the sql;

```
    //the age advance search
    switch (Request::get('member_age')):
        case '18-25':
            $age = " AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(yy, -26, GetDate()) And Date_Add(yy, -18, GetDate()) ";
            break;
        case '26-35':
            $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(yy, -35, GetDate()) And Date_Add(yy, -26, GetDate())";
            break;
        case '36-45':
            $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(yy, -45, GetDate()) And Date_Add(yy, -36, GetDate())";
            break;
        case '46-55':
            $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(yy, -55, GetDate()) And Date_Add(yy, -46, GetDate())";
            break;
        case '56-65':
            $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Between Date_Add(yy, -65, GetDate()) And Date_Add(yy, -56, GetDate())";
            break;
        case '65+':
            $age = "AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Between Date_Add(yy, -999999, GetDate()) And Date_Add(yy, -55, GetDate())";
            break;
        default:
            $age = "";
    endswitch;
```

And my sql:

```
    $search_people_sql = "SELECT *
                          FROM users
                          LEFT JOIN friends
                            ON users.user_id  = friends.friends_friend  
                          LEFT JOIN friend_request 
                            ON users.user_id  = friend_request.friend_request_to 
                            OR users.user_id  = friend_request.friend_request_from  
                          LEFT JOIN user_personal_information
                            ON user_personal_information.user_personal_information_user = friends.friends_friend
                          WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', user_personal_information.user_firstname, user_personal_information.user_surname) LIKE ?
                          AND user_enabled = 1
                          AND user_id      != ?
                          ".$age."
```

but am getting this error

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '-26, GetDate()) And Date_Add(yy, -18, GetDate()) '

Comment: `GetDate()` is `sql server` syntax.  You should use `Now()`.

Comment: where is the rest of php code? till  `bindParam` and `execute` ?

Comment: so you use sql or mysql server?

Comment: ful code: http://pastebin.com/m2Jxgvtk

Comment: change `date_add` calls according to correct original syntax `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -55 Year)`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: @Alex which way would I put it? sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is not an answer, but just big comment.

You have :

```
AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(yy, -26, GetDate()) And Date_Add(yy, -18, GetDate())";
```

this syntax is wrong :

1. There is no `GetDate()` function in mysql
2. `DATE_ADD` has different syntax according to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

If you use mysql this part could looks like:

```
AND user_birthdate BETWEEN Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -26 YEAR) And Date_Add(NOW(), INTERVAL -18 YEAR)";
```

So you have to change all your strings like that to correct mysql syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Date_Add(yy, -26, Now())

you may have to CAST the dates

CAST(Date_Add(yy, -26, Now())) AS DATE